# Plugin registration for a host

Tags: c#, plugins, mef, registration

What would be a good way for a plugin to register itself with its host?

I am using C# and this is for a WPF application. I am designing a plugin system. Since I am only in the design stages, I do not need details. I will use MEF. In my design, I want each plugin to register itself as a plugin for the host. In this context, "register" is non-specific; I just want a way for the host to be able to automatically locate each available plugin. I am assuming that the only registration data necessary will be the complete path and filename of the DLL of each plugin; in other words, upon installation, each plugin will add itself to a list of plugin paths. The installer of the plugin will need to be able to find the list and I am asking what would be a good way for that to happen. The traditional solution is for all plugins to be placed in a specified folder, but that requires the user to do that. Theoretically the plugins could find the host and determine what folder to use, but if we do that then the plugin could go one more step and add itself to a list of plugins. I am assuming it will be possible to design a way to make it easier for plugin developers to include the registration in the plugin installation than requiring the plugin installer to install the plugin in a specified plugin directory. Either way, it should make plugin installation easy for the user.

For example, strong names are supposedly designed for similar purposes, but Microsoft says that strong names should not be used for EXEs. The explanation for why not is not clear, so perhaps a strong name would work for this purpose.

I am essentially only asking for guidance toward what to learn about.

Comment: What I would do is look at how popular plug-in aware applications handle this problem. Perhaps Visual Studio and Eclipse. By the way since you decided to use MEF and WPF you shoud have a look at Microsoft Prism.

Comment: I think I am already familiar with other plugin systems. Are you? The common solution is to **essentially** do what the DirectoryCatalog class of MEF does; that is, usually all plugins are put into a specified directory. The problem is that it either requires the user to do that or it requires the user to install software in a specified location. I am hoping to design something that is easier for the user. I have tentavely decided to create a plugin manager class library; I am hoping that is an elegant and flexible solution.

Comment: Then you should have a look at installation development tools (such as NSIS, WiX, InstallShield etc.) and check how to 1) add prerequisites (the host application) to the plug-in setup projects and 2) locate the installation directory of the prerequisite. Your problem is not how to register the plug-ins but how to deploy them. Happy New Year! ps. The add-in frameworks that I have used are MEF, Mono.Addins and System.AddIn. MEF and Mono.Addins I highly recommend.

Comment: WiX and InstallShield both create msi (Windows Installer) files. If you are familiar with the Windows Installer then a clue to how to do this would help. Yes, of course I need to learn the details. I will. I was asking in case someone was familiar with the Windows Installer.